# WebSocket compression in netty

Tags: java, websocket, server, netty

In the [WebSocket-Server example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/ed4a89082bb29b9e7d869c5d25d6b9ea8fc9d25b/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerInitializer.java) from the netty repository the WebSocket-Server gets initialized like this

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    if (sslCtx != null) {
        pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
    }
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
    pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerCompressionHandler());
    pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerHandler());
}
```

But the **WebSocketServerCompressionHandler** is not shipped with the **netty-all** package. Is it an outdated example or am I missing another package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Netty are you using? The example you linked to is for Netty 5.0.

WebSocketServerCompressionHandler is in the netty-codec-http package for Netty 5.0 which should be included in netty-all.

If you are using Netty 4.0 or Netty 4.1 try the following example -
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerInitializer.java

Comment: Yes I'm using 4.0.30. I thought the examples would be for the stable version. your example has a WebSocketServerHandler which is also not a part of the nett-all package. I use WebSocketServerProtocolHandler instead.

Comment: Its a part of the example - https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerHandler.java